# Stubbing method doesn't work: JDBC statement in try with resources failing with NPE when using Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock, powermockito

So here's the method:

```
 protected void writeData(String bucket, String key, String tableName) throws SQLException{
    try {
        Class.forName(DRIVER_NAME);
        try (
                Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(redshiftDBUrl, DBUtils.getConnectionProperties(redshiftDBUsername, redshiftDBPassword));
                Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ){
            String query = String.format(SQL_QUERY, tableName, bucket, key, redshiftIAMRole);
            LOGGER.debug("query is: " + query);
            statement.executeUpdate(query);
            LOGGER.info("Copying to redshift done");
        }
        catch(SQLException ex){
            LOGGER.error("Failed to write data to Redshift", ex);
            throw new SQLException("Failed to write data to Redshift");
        }
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        LOGGER.error("Unable to find the driver!", ex);
        throw new SQLException(ex);
    }
}
```

It's failing at :

> Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

Here's the test code:

```
@Test 
public void testWriteDataWithValidData() throws SQLException{

    PowerMockito.mockStatic(DriverManager.class);
    Connection connection = mock(Connection.class);
    PowerMockito.when(DriverManager.getConnection(REDSHIFT_DB_URL, REDSHIFT_DB_USERNAME, REDSHIFT_DB_PASSWORD)).thenReturn(connection);
    Statement statement = mock(Statement.class);
    when(connection.createStatement()).thenReturn(statement);
    when(statement.executeUpdate(SQL_QUERY)).thenReturn(1);

    ingestionRequestHandler.writeData(S3_BUCKET, S3_KEY, TABLE_NAME);
}
```

At the start of the Test class, I have

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(IngestionRequestHandler.class)
```

I thought that mocking and stubbing in a particular order might matter so changed the code to:

```
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(DriverManager.class);
        Connection connection = mock(Connection.class);
        Statement statement = mock(Statement.class);
        when(connection.createStatement()).thenReturn(statement);
        when(statement.executeUpdate(SQL_QUERY)).thenReturn(1);
        PowerMockito.when(DriverManager.getConnection(REDSHIFT_DB_URL, REDSHIFT_DB_USERNAME, REDSHIFT_DB_PASSWORD)).thenReturn(connection);
```

But this doesn't help as well.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should read a bit about "try with resources" before you're trying abuse it ;)

Comment: Using PowerMock(-ito) is a surrender to bad design. Acquiring/instantiating dependencies violates the *Single Responsibility Pattern*.  You should create the `connection` object outside the unit and pass it in via *dependency injection*.

Answer (score 0):

You have to annotate your test case with `@PrepareForTest` for **both** the class under test and the `DriverManager` class e.g.

```
@PrepareForTest({DriverManager.class, IngestionRequestHandler.class})
```

With that annotation in place, the following test will successfully mock the `DriverManager`:

```
@Test
public void testWriteDataWithValidData() throws SQLException {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(DriverManager.class);
    Connection connection = Mockito.mock(Connection.class);

    // you may prefer to provide explicit values for these next two parameters
    String url = Mockito.anyString();
    Properties usernameAndPassword = Mockito.any(Properties.class);
    PowerMockito.when(DriverManager.getConnection(url, usernameAndPassword)).thenReturn(connection);

    Statement statement = Mockito.mock(Statement.class);
    Mockito.when(connection.createStatement()).thenReturn(statement);

    // you may prefer to provide an explicit value from the base query and your bucket, key and tableName parameters
    String sqlQuery = Mockito.anyString();
    Mockito.when(statement.executeUpdate(sqlQuery)).thenReturn(1);

    ingestionRequestHandler.writeData(S3_BUCKET, S3_KEY, TABLE_NAME);
}
```